# error compiling gazebo installation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, some weeks ago i trying to install gazebo in a workspace but everytime it fail, when i do the rosmake i obtain this error:

```
jose@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosmake simulator_gazebo
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['simulator_gazebo']                                                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/jose/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130129-095222                                 
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['simulator_gazebo'] to:
['gazebo_plugins', 'gazebo_tools', 'gazebo', 'gazebo_worlds', 'gazebo_msgs', 'gazebo_tests']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface                                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> ivcon [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< ivcon ROS_NOBUILD in package ivcon                                                             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom                                                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                                                            
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                                     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser                                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice                                                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                                                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> srdf [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                                         
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< srdf ROS_NOBUILD in package srdf                                                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> resource_retriever [ make ]                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< resource_retriever ROS_NOBUILD in package resource_retriever                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure                                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> collada_urdf [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< collada_urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_urdf                                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]                                                                         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xacro [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs  No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo_msgs [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xacro ROS_NOBUILD in package xacro                                                             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< polled_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package polled_camera                                             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs  No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs                                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl                                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> convex_decomposition [ make ]                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< convex_decomposition ROS_NOBUILD in package convex_decomposition                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test                                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> simmechanics_to_urdf [ make ]                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< simmechanics_to_urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package simmechanics_to_urdf                               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> timestamp_tools [ make ]                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< timestamp_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package timestamp_tools                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_nodelet [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions                                     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package test_nodelet                                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                                                                  
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> robot_state_publisher [ make ]                                                                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< robot_state_publisher ROS_NOBUILD in package robot_state_publisher                             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo_msgs [PASS] [ 50.95 seconds ]                                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo [ make ]                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lineszebo: 906.9 sec ]                                                   [ 1 Active 61/66 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  touch wiped
  mkdir -p build
  if [ ! -f md5sums/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd.tgz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file md5sums/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd.tgz.md5sum" && false; fi
  `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/gazebo/groovy/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd.tgz build/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd.tgz `awk {'print $1'} md5sums/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd.tgz.md5sum`
  [rosbuild] Downloading https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/gazebo/groovy/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd.tgz to build/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd.tgz...Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 56, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 28, in main
      urllib.urlretrieve(uri, dest)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
      return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
      fp = self.open(url, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
      return getattr(self, name)(url)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 436, in open_https
      h.endheaders(data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
      self._send_output(message_body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
      self.send(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
      self.connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
      self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
      ciphers=ciphers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
      self.do_handshake()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
  make[1]: *** [build/gazebo-r3c730325a4dd/unpacked] Error 1
  make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo»
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (message):
    Build of Gazebo failed
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package gazebo written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/jose/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130129-095222/gazebo/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo [FAIL] [ 906.96 seconds ]                                                               
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package gazebo. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.               
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Built 62 packages with 1 failures.                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] /home/jose/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130129-095222
```

i really need help with this problem, someone could help me????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53613/error-compiling-gazebo-installation/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like it could not fetch the gazebo tarball, you will need an internet connection to build this package. If you had internet at the time, then try again as it might have been a temporary outage or something.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0